# Display a pdf file using colab

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, pdf

I have saved some images of my work in .pdf format using matplotlib, I know this is my fault from the beginning and I should save it directly as image but I did not know that I can not display pdf files on colab. To get these results I need another 10 days which is not good choice for me.
Actually I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747853/matplotlib-how-to-load-and-show-a-pdf-image) which express my problem precisely but there was not answer.
It just seems strange to me that using matplotlib I can save pdf files but I can not load them using it again.
I just need to display the pdf file in colab cell ,I have tried:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['myfile.pdf'],shell=True)
```

and this was the result:

<subprocess.Popen at 0x7f4d6a395978>

another methods as in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19453338/opening-pdf-file) do not work for me

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470099/view-pdf-image-in-an-ipython-notebook?

Comment: using wand and PDF class give me error unable to connect. I do not know it does not work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [View pdf image in an iPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470099/view-pdf-image-in-an-ipython-notebook)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok this works for me, maybe there are a simpler solution but for now this works

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
from IPython.display import display, Image

images = convert_from_path("myfile.pdf")
for i, image in enumerate(images):    
    fname = "image" + str(i) + ".png"
    image.save(fname, "PNG")
Image(fname, width=600, height=300)
```

Answer (score 2):

In a Jupyter notebook / Colab you can simply

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path

images = convert_from_path("myfile.pdf")
images[0]  # first page
```

The image will be able to render as the cell output. No need for `IPython.display`